# Accessing a value from Dask using .loc

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, dask

For the life of me, I cant figure how to combine these two dataframes. I am using the newest most updated versions of all softwares, including Python, Pandas and Dask.

```
#pandasframe has 10k rows and 3 columns - 
['monkey','banana','furry']

#daskframe has 1.5m rows, 1column, 135 partitions - 
row.index: 'monkey_banana_furry'
row.mycolumn = 'happy flappy tuna'
```

my dask dataframe has a string as its index for accessing,
but when i do `daskframe.loc[index_str]` it returns a dask dataframe, but i thought it was supposed to return one single specific row. and i dont know how to access the row/value that i need from that dataframe. what i want is to input the index, and output one specific value.

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Are you asking about .loc or .iloc? Your question title says the latter. .iloc is not supported in dask dataframes.

Answer (score 2):

Even [`pandas.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) don't return a scalar if you don't specify a label for the columns.

Anyways, to get a scalar in your case, first, you need to add [`dask.dataframe.DataFrame.compute`](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.dataframe.DataFrame.compute.html?highlight=compute#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.compute) so you can get a pandas dataframe (since [`dask.dataframe.DataFrame.loc`](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.dataframe.DataFrame.loc.html?highlight=loc#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.loc) returns a dask dataframe). And only then, you can use the pandas `.loc`.

Assuming (`dfd`) is your *dask dataframe*, try this :

```
dfd.loc[index_str].compute().loc[index_str, "happy flappy tuna"]
```

Or this :

```
dfd.loc[index_str, "happy flappy tuna"].compute().iloc[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use .compute() as it...

> turns a Dask dataframe into a Pandas dataframe.

According to the docs

So, if you wanted to filter your dataframe by a specific name, you could do:

```
df[df['Names'] == 'MyName'].compute()
```

Moreover, if you do `type(df)`, you'll get `dask.dataframe.core.DataFrame`, but `type(df.compute())` will give you `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame`, so you can treat the result as any pandas dataframe.

Just consider that by doing this, you will store the data in RAM as the traditional pandas way.